# i have to convert the string 08:00 AM TO 08:00PM to half hour slots

Tags: java

i have to convert the string 08:00 AM TO 08:00PM to half hour slots like 08:00AM TO 08:30 AM the value of the string will change like from 07:00AM TO 08:00PM

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: The question and description is rather confusing... Could you please expand and also post any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want a string to increase by half an hour from 7:00 am to 8:00pm .If thats the case then you can do it via a loop .I've Made once exclusively for you.

```
public static void main(String [] args){

       String l = "7:00am";
         String q = "8:00pm";
         String j="";
         String k = "";
         String g = "";
         int v = 0;
         int i = 0;

         while (l.equals(q)== false){
               j="";
               i=0;
              while (i<2){
            if (l.charAt(i)== (':')){
                break;
            }
            j=j+l.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
   k = l.substring(j.length()+1,l.length()-2);
   if (l.equals(q)== true){
break;
   }
   else if (j.equals("11")&& k.equals("30")){
      if ((l.charAt(l.length()-2))==('a')) {
       v=Integer.parseInt(j)+1;
      g=""+v+":00pm"; 
      System.out.println(g);
  l="1:00pm"; 


   }else if((l.charAt(l.length()-2))==('p')){
      v=Integer.parseInt(j)+1;
      g=""+v+":00am"; 
      System.out.println(g);
  l="1:00am"; 

   }
   }
   else if ((l.charAt(l.length()-2))==('a') && k.equals("30")){

       v=Integer.parseInt(j)+1;
      g=""+v+":00am"; 
      System.out.println(g);
  l=g;

   }
   else if((l.charAt(l.length()-2))==('a') && k.equals("00")){
     v=Integer.parseInt(j);
      g=""+v+":30am"; 
      System.out.println(g);
      l=g;

   }
   else if ((l.charAt(l.length()-2))==('p') && k.equals("00") ){
        v= Integer.parseInt(j);
      g=""+v+":30pm"; 
      System.out.println(g);
      l=g;

   }
   else if((l.charAt(l.length()-2))==('p') && k.equals("30")){
          v=Integer.parseInt(j)+1;
      g=""+v+":00pm"; 
      System.out.println(g);
      l=g;
   }

   }   
}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I corrected it just put q instead of y.actually it still works without the condition        '    if (l.equals(q)== true){
    break;
    }' .